# jQuery animate() producing wild results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover, mouseleave

I'm pretty new to jQuery and I've been fooling around with its animate() but I've run into two problems. My code below is basically supposed to expand the characterwindow when the mouse is hovering over it, changing the text inside once it's expanded. Then characterwindow should retract back to it's original size when the mouse goes off the now larger version of it, changing the text as it starts to retract.

**My problem** is that this is just generally screwy as hell. If you just zoom your mouse in and out a few times it constantly expands and retracts for a bit without you doing anything, and the text flickers when you go in and out and doesn't even disappear before the retraction like it should.

I tried using the callback parameter for the mouseover, but sometimes the text would show up before the animation actually finished.

Is this a limitation of jQuery, JavaScript, my server, my client, or what? If there's a better/more efficient way to implement this I'd be grateful if you showed it.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="characterwindow" style="width:80px;height:23px;border-radius:15px;">
<div id="characterwindowgraphic" style="border-radius:15px;background-color:#1C1C1C;height:23px;width:80px;">
<center><p1 id="characterwindowtext" style="color:white;">Character</p1></center>
</div></div>

<script>

$("#characterwindow").mouseover(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$("#characterwindowtext").html("Character<br><br>Name<br>Details");},500);
    $("#characterwindow").css({"width":"300px","height":"250px"});
    $("#characterwindowgraphic").animate({
        width:'300px',
        height:'250px'
    },500);
});

$("#characterwindow").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#characterwindowtext").text("Character");
    $("#characterwindow").css({"width":"80px","height":"23px"});
    $("#characterwindowgraphic").animate({
        width:'80px',
        height:'23px'
    },500);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `<p1>` to [`<p>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) - though I doubt thats the problem

Comment: Would that really matter? I defined the p1 class in some CSS but I don't think the absence of it really changes anything here.

Comment: `p1` is not a `class` in this case - it's a tag name. There are a predefined set of tag names you can use; `p1` is not one of them.

Comment: Try changing `mouseover` to `mouseenter`. Mouseover with changing element sizes could potentially cause issues as the event would be triggering more than you expect as the element changes sizes and the mouse enters/leaves child elements.

Comment: @Ian Ah so I should've done <p class="p1"></p> then defined the class in CSS? Honestly I'll probably just start doing <p style="css stuff"></p> if that works. As you can see I'm still learning all of this. xD

Comment: @winterblood Good call, I bet that's it. `mouseover` has bubbling "problems"

Comment: @Cains Exactly. Don't start setting the `style` attribute - use classes or other CSS rules to target elements. Well if you have questions about your code more, we're happy to help

Comment: @winterblood With mouseenter it still repeatedly expands and retracts when you put your mouse in and out of the div a few times

Comment: @winterblood it has nothing to do with mouseover or mouseenter.. this is one of the downfalls of jQuery unfortunately. animating on hover is a no no.

Comment: @Ian Should I not use the style attribute on divs as well, setting those by classes and css rules? Why is the style attribute less favorable?

Comment: @Cains you want to separate your styling, displaying and javascript to separate files making editing and updating much easier

Comment: @Cains this also makes your codes more portable or reusable

Comment: @Cains Setting the `style` mixes styling with structure (which should be separate), it's not reusable, and it causes problems with CSS levels of precedence

Comment: @Cains it is about separating your content from your style, and the ease of updating it brings. It is a whole lot easier to change a single class in your css than it is to change multiple inline styles.

Comment: @jayharris If this is a drawback of jQuery, is there some other method you know of for animation on mouse hover? And thank you to all three of your for your responses, I'll stop using the style attribute and define css rules more.

Comment: @Cains Good to hear :) And it's not a jQuery drawback - it's a "drawback" of the `mouseover` event. But as winterblood said, use the `mouseenter` event instead.

Comment: @Cains don't animate on hover, instead create a popup box that appears then disappears, this will give you a more consistent result.

Comment: @Ian i stand corrected lol

Comment: @jayharris No big deal :) You can't blame the library that handles the behavior :) It's just that `mouseover` occurs for descendants as well, and bubbles, causing "false positives" if you may

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your animation are getting queued. So it will not start another animation before the first one is done.

To stop that you can use `stop()` before the animation like that :

```
$("#characterwindowgraphic").stop().animate({
    width:'300px',
    height:'250px'
},500);
```

it will clear the queue.

Or you can call your animate like that :

```
$("#characterwindowgraphic").stop().animate({
    width:'300px',
    height:'250px'
},{duration : 500, queue : false});
```

Also as winterblood said in the comments, use `mouseleave` and `mouseenter`.

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U6S3S/

**EDIT :** Also, instead of using a timeout for the html, use animate callback function. If you take the first method, it will be like that :

```
$("#characterwindowgraphic").stop().animate({
    width:'300px',
    height:'250px'
},500, function(){
    $("#characterwindowtext").html("Character<br><br>Name<br>Details")
});
```

And if you choose the second method, it will be like that :

```
$("#characterwindowgraphic").stop().animate({
    width:'300px',
    height:'250px'
},{
   duration : 500, 
   queue : false,
   complete : function(){
      $("#characterwindowtext").html("Character<br><br>Name<br>Details")
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! I figured it was something about it queueing the mouseenters and mouseleaves.